# Why does bash look different in different flavours of linux/unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, command-line

I'm doing some work on a server that runs CentOS at the moment, and the prompt looks different from the Ubuntu bash command line. I initially thought it was a different shell, but `echo $SHELL` showed me that it was still bash.

I was mainly wondering whether this is a configuration thing, and where this is set up, for example, my ubuntu bash prompt:

```
tom@tom-PC:~$
```

compared with the CentOS bash command prompt:

```
[root@server217-174-254-199 ~]#
```

Aside from the obvious differences in machine name and user (and the # caused by being logged in as root) CentOS has [ ~] around the user@machine whereas ubuntu prefers a simple :~ before the prompt

Comment: Linux & Unix question ? Anyway, Patrick's answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a question of taste: everyone can configure his PROMPT-line with the env-variable PS1.

For example:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w$'
```

gives

```
user@host:directory$
```

whereas directory is '~' for your home-dir.

Comment: yeah i just realised the ~ was for home and felt like a bit of an idiot, was hoping to edit the post before anyone saw :P

Comment: @Tom why? Prompt customizing is a fine thing worth to learn more about...

Comment: haha I just mean that I realised I already knew what the ~ was and had just not thought about it, was going to edit my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Here it looks this way:

```
glglgl@schleppiSB [1314183327: Wed Aug 24 2011 12:55:27, 9/62261] 
 -0  0  ~/p>
```

even with nice colors. Why? Because my `~/.bashrc` contains the line

```
PS1='\e[1;32;44m\u\e[1;30m@\e[1;34m\h\e[0m [\e[1;43;33m$(shellprompttemp=$?; LANG=C date +"%s: %a %b %d %Y"; exit $shellprompttemp)\e[1;37m \t\e[0m, \e[1;35m\#\e[0m/\e[1;36m\!\e[0m] \e[1;31;7m${?/#0}\e[0m\e[0m\n$(hg prompt '\''{\e[41;37mhg: {status}\e[0m\n}'\'' 2>/dev/null; dirs -p -v | tac | awk '\''{ $0=sprintf("%2d %s",NR-1,$0); sub(/^ */,"&-"); print; }'\'')> '
```

With `PS1`, you have full control over how your prompt looks like. You get more info with `man bash`, section `PROMPTING`.

Answer (score 1):

Different distros are preconfigured for different user populations.  On a desktop, you mainly just expect to see a simple prompt and maybe the current directory; for a server distro, it is useful for the prompt on each server to be different from every other server, so that you can tell at a glance where you are logged into (the admin typically logs into more than one server at the same time).  Other than that, though, it's just a matter of taste, typically the taste of the Bash maintainer for your distro.  Out of the box, the default prompt in Bash is just `bash$` (where the dollar sign is replaced with a hash sign when you are logged in as root).